# Handle missing QuickTime plugin with Firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins, quicktime

I have a web page that uses the QuickTime plugin to display a 360-degree panorama file. The code to display the 360 looks like this:

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="260" width="320">
<param name="src" value="/images/x/360/x.pano">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="loop" value="false">
<param name="controller" value="true">
<embed src="/images/x/360/x.pano" autoplay="true" loop="false" controller="true" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" height="260" width="320">
</object>
```

The problem I'm running into is that when a user goes to this page and doesn't have the right plugin, an error message appears at the top of the browser, saying plugins are missing to display the page, and there's a button to install missing plugins.

Clicking the button goes to the Firefox "Plugin Finder Service," which displays the message "No suitable plugins were found. Unknown plugin (application/octet-stream)"

My questions is, how can I set up my code so Firefox recognizes that it needs the Quicktime plugin to display the content, so that the "Plugin Finder Service" suggests the user install the QT plugin, instead of this generic message?

(FWIW when the plugin is installed, it all works perfectly and that code is fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing ur embed tag's pluginspage attribute from,

```
<embed src="/images/x/360/x.pano" autoplay="true" loop="false" controller="true" 
 pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" height="260" width="320">
```

to

```
<embed src="/images/x/360/x.pano" autoplay="true" loop="false" controller="true"
 pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" height="260" width="320">
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the MIME type.  Add

> type="video/quicktime"

to the attributes of your embed tag.