# Handle missing quicktime plugin with IE

Tags: html, plugins, quicktime

My question is similar to [Handle missing QuickTime plugin with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613558/handle-missing-quicktime-plugin-with-firefox) However, in my case, Firefox detects that the plugin is missing and directs me to the proper page from which to download the plugin. Internet Explorer 8, on the other hand, just displays a broken image icon (not the QuickTime symbol).

This is my code:

```html
<embed 
starttime="00:05:22.5"
qtsrcdontusebrowser="true" 
pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" 
controller="false" 
autoplay="false" 
kioskmode="true" 
autohref="true" 
href="IITM%20-%2003%20-%20Mechanical%20Events.mov" 
src="IITM%20-%2003%20-%20Mechanical%20Events.mov" 
target="quicktimeplayer"
width="384"
height="128">
</embed>
```

Am I missing something that IE needs? If the user has the QuickTime plugin, the video plays just fine in IE 8.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Yes. That's a possibility. We use QuickTime for the integrated chapter navigation (that's essential for our lecture videos). There's at least one Flash/HTML5 player that supports chapters, but when I tried it, it was to buggy to use. Also, QuickTime's MP4 chapter format works for both iOS devices and desktop computers(running QuickTime).

Comment: @PeeHaa. Sorry, I think I deleted your comment. It was something along the lines of: "Why not ditch QuickTime?".

Comment: more examples here on how to use the object tag and force it to use WMP vs QuickTime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631559/embed-a-video-in-internet-explorer-without-flash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something that IE needs?

You miss that IE is in the camp of `<object>` whereas Firefox is in the camp of `<embed>`.

You find the IE software documented at the Vendors website: http://www.microsoft.com/ which should provide all details you might need to find out to solve that problem for you.

- [Internet Explorer: object element | object object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Book Excerpt: The Client-side  Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952644.aspx)
- ...

Comment: That's it. And there's more info in the [HTML Scripting Guide for QuickTime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001525-2-HTMLScripting)